# How can I make power operation on tensor list

Tags: python, theano

How to make power operation on tensor list in Theano?

```
import theano.tensor as T

a = T.sum(w**2)
```

Where w is a list contains several TensorType (float64,4D), above codes make the error:

```
TypeError:unsupported operand type (s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "power operation on tensor list"? Do you want to square all tensors one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, for example, `w` is a Python list of Theano symbolic matrices,

```
w = [theano.tensor.matrix() for _ in xrange(10)]
```

then one can get a Python list of symbolic expressions for the sum of the square of each matrix using a regular Python list comprehension:

```
a = [T.sum(w_i ** 2) for w_i in w]
```

If you then want the symbolic sum of the entries in `a`, just use

```
a_sum = T.sum(a)
```

Note that this all assumes the number of entries in `w` is known in advance, i.e. the size of `w` doesn't need to be symbolic. Theano doesn't yet fully support symbolic lists but partial support is available via [`typed_list`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/typed_list.html).